# My drop down selector items are not saving in db

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, sql-server-2014

I am new for MVC5, I am using MVC5.0 and entity frame work code first approach.
I have a drop down list, drop down list values are not constant, by default drop down list values are adding by another page when I create a new page. but that particular drop down field value is not taking when I select from drop down(I mean I can able to select but not saving in Db.). Here when I give validations I am not able to add because it showing error message states "Department field is required ". But by default I have a depart name in that field. please help me.

Thank you very much in advance.
Ali
Below is my code

### View Page

```
  <div class="form-group">
 @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Department, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
<div class="col-md-6" style="width:275px;">
  @Html.DropDownList("ID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Department, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
 </div>
```

### below code for Controller

```
  //Get Method

public ActionResult Add()
{
 PopulateDivisionDropDownList();
 return View();
}  

//Post Method
[httpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
 public ActionResult Add([Bind(Include = "ID,Code,Name,Department,CreatedDateandTime")] DivisionViewModel divisionViewModel)
{


        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.DivisionViewModels.Add(divisionViewModel);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("List");
        }

        //below line for finder
        ViewBag.Name = new SelectList(db.DivisionViewModels, "ID", "Name", divisionViewModel.Name);
        PopulateDivisionDropDownList(divisionViewModel.ID);
        db.SaveChanges();            
        return View(divisionViewModel);
     }
    //below method for finder
    private void PopulateDivisionDropDownList(object selectedDepartment = null)
    {
        var departmentquery = from dept in db.DepartmentViewModels
                           orderby dept.Name
                           select dept;
        db.SaveChanges();
        ViewBag.ID = new SelectList(departmentquery, "ID", "Name", selectedDepartment);
        //db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

---

Department is my master page, If I fill department form, depart name is showing in division master page by default. here after selecting department name in division page, these values are not saving in db. please help me.

Thank you.
Ali

Comment: Your creating a dropdownlist for property `ID`, not `Department` Always use the strongly typed `DropDownListFor()` and use a view model (do not use data models in your view, and do not use `ViewBag`)